# merging some scrartcl-documents in one document

Tags: include

Hello StackExchangeCommunity,

I'm writing some nice short stories with 20-40 sections in LaTeX with `scrartcl`. Every short stories has an titlepage, table of contents with all sections and after this every section.

Now, I want to create an overall-document with every short-story. It will beginn with a title-pages and a table of contents in which the beginning of every story will be there. And after this, I will import every story as an tex-File in which the own title-page, the personal table of contents of the stories and the story itself will be.

Does anyone can tell me how to do this? Is that possible in the way I want?

I'm using LaTeX with TeXShop on El Capitan. Thank you very much.

My main document is something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\chead{- \thepage \hspace{1pt} - }

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\begin{large}
Some information for titlepage
\end{large}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{3}

\include{Content1.tex}
\include{Content2.tex}

\section{Test}
\kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```

And now I have two other files, content1 and content2 with content like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\chead{- \thepage \hspace{1pt} - }

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}
Some content for the titlepage
\end{center}
\end{large}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{3}

\section{Section 55}
\kant[11-15]

\section{Section 56}
\kant[20-21]

\end{document}
```

It is compiling with no error, but nothing from `content1.tex` and content2.tex is inside the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX Lukas! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Even if it might appear a bit strange, it's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) -- btw, you can change your username to something more telling than `user103851` !) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: As starting points, you can have a look on the `\include{<.tex-file>}` command, [How to create inner section like environment with sub-table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155411/64454), and [Using \maketitle twice in the same article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192772/64454)

Comment: Crosspost on golatex: http://golatex.de/mehrere-latex-geschichten-zusammenmixen-t17180.html